# GraphQL Route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I've created a Rails app using GraphQL and one simple model.  I can access the API in the GraphIQL IDE via `http://localhost:3000/graphiql`, but should I also be able to access it via `https://locahost:3000/graphql` so that I can use that in my frontend app?

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  if Rails.env.development?
      mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
    end
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The route `/graphql` requires you to have a `GraphqlController` in your `app/controllers/` directory which respond to the `execute` action.

Comment: _"but should I also be able to access it via[...]/graphql so that I can use that in my frontend app?"_ this `/graphql` endpoint is only available for POST requests, not GET, meaning that typing the URL `https://locahost:3000/graphql` in your browser and hit enter, it will send a GET request, which will result in a 404. Use Curl or Postman to generate POST requests to a specific endpoint (or use `/graphiql` (GET) which will do POST requests to `/graphql`)